# How to center list items for mobile screens

Tags: css, html-lists

When I shrink the browser for mobile screens,lists which are in footer, doesnt seem centered.

You can see it on this link:

https://www.sac-ekimi.deniz-tasarim.site/bize-ulasin/

( "Hakkımızda" and "Destek" lists )

How to center them?

Here is the codes for these lists:

```
  <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" >
                    <h5 style="text-align: center;"><?php 
// Using the global argment
global $redux_demo; // Same as your opt_name
echo $redux_demo['footer-text-1']; ?></h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li style="display: inline-block; "><a href="#">

                            <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
       'theme_location' => 'menu_name',
    'container'         => "nav",  
        'container_class'   => "topnav",  
       'container_id'      => "topnav",   
       'menu_class'        => "topmenu",  
        'menu_id'           => "topmenu",
   )
);  

            ?>

                            </a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 footermenu" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
                    <h5 style="text-align: center;"><?php 
// Using the global argment
global $redux_demo; // Same as your opt_name
echo $redux_demo['footer-text-2']; ?></h5>
                    <ul >
                        <li style="display: inline-block;"><a href="#"   >

                       <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
       'theme_location' => 'menu_name2',
    'container'         => "nav",  
        'container_class'   => "topnav",  
       'container_id'      => "topnav",   
       'menu_class'        => "topmenu",  
        'menu_id'           => "topmenu",
   )
);  

            ?>




                            </a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the browser is adding `padding-left: 40px;` to all `ul`s on the page as part of its default styling. You could fix this by adding a [CSS Reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to your project but at this point, that will likely break a lot more code than it will fix. Its generally advised to plug in a CSS Reset at the start of a project.

To resolve this issue alone, I'd recommend overwriting the the `ul#topmenu` like so:

```
#topmenu {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

This **will** resolve the extra padding you're seeing on your `ul`s.

This **will not** completely resolve the alignment issues you're seeing on smaller screens. If a single word is longer than the parent containing it, it will overflow past the edge of the parent so as to keep the text readable.

I'd recommend re-flowing your footer on smaller screen sizes to be stacked.

Should look something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #myFooter .col-sm-3 {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  #myFooter .col-sm-3 ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks now its good on mobile screen.however it doesnt seem centered for desktops.how to solve it? you can look at the link again. Also mostly thing which consume my time is css.How can I learn it? thanks

Comment: Yeah that use of `padding-left: 0;` is only on the mobile breakpoints now. If you add that outside of the media query it should fix on desktop too.

Answer (score 0):

For media queries to work, you need to include:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Between the tags.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp